# Multer not Receiving Files in Express Backend from Axios POST Request

Tags: javascript, vue.js, express, multer

I am currently facing an issue with file uploads from a Vue.js client to an Express backend using Axios and Multer. The problem seems to be related to the field name mismatch between the FormData key on the client side and the multer configuration on the server side.

Client-Side Code:

```js
const uploadFile = async (file) => {
  // ... (existing code)

  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("image", file);  // Field name mismatch?

  // ... (existing code)

  try {
    const { data } = await uploadImageService(formData, config);
  } catch (e) {
    // ... (existing code)
  }
};

async function uploadImageService(form, config) {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.post(apiEndpoint + "upload/image", form, config);
    return data;
  } catch (ex) {
    return ex.response.data;
  }
}
```

Backend-Side Code:

```js
const multer = require("multer");
const upload = multer({ dest: "uploads/" });

restaurantRouter.post('/upload/image', upload.array("imageUploader"), ImageController.uploadImage);


ImageController.uploadImage =  async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const files = req.files;

    } catch (error) {
    // return error response
        return res.status(500).json({
            status: "error",
            message: error.message,
        });
    }
}
```